# how to get last committed offset from read_committed Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am using the transactional KafkaProducer to send messages to a topic. This works fine. I use a KafkaConsumer with read_committed isolation level and I have an issue with the seek and seekToEnd methods. According to the documentation, the seek and seekToEnd methods give me the LSO (Last Stable Offset). But this is a bit confusing. As it gives me always the same value, the END of the topic. No matter if the last entry is committed (by the Producer) or part of an aborted transaction.
Example, after I abort the last 5 tries to insert 20_000 messages, the last 100_000 records should not be read by the Consumer. But during a seekToEnd it moves to the end of the Topic (including the 100_000 messages). But the poll() does not return them.

I am looking for a way to retrieve the Last Committed Offset (so the last successful committed message by the Producer). There seems to be no proper API method for this. So do I need to roll my own?

Option would be to move back and poll until no more records are retrieved, this would result in the last committed message. But I would assume that Kafka provides this method.

We use Kafka 1.0.0.

Comment: Can you provide your full configuration? Also, can you try to `seek` to `-3`? `-3` is a sentinel value representing the `last stable offset`.

Answer (score 1):

The class `KafkaConsumer` has some nice methods like: `partitionFor`, `begginingOffsets` and `endOffsets` also `commited` and `position`.

Check which one fits to your needs. Especially carefully consider all 4 offset-related methods.
The method `partitionFor` returns complete metadata object with other information, but can be useful for enriching the logging.

Comment: I have raised a JIRA @ Kafka. Seek and SeekToEnd, endOffsets etc move to the last message on the Topic, regardless of the message being part of a committed transaction or not....

Comment: Actually we need something like seekToLastCommittedMessage

Comment: Can you specify how did you get the last successfully committed message by the Producer ? As per my understanding, seekToEnd() and endOffsets() will take you to the end of your topic. In my case, I have 100 message in a topic. Offset#96 was the last committed message by a producer.  Offset#96-100 are uncommitted messages. How do I retrieve last committed message ?

Comment: @CoenDamen can you please link the kafka JIRA? thanks!

Comment: @CoenDamen any update about how you retrieved the Last Committed Offset of transactional producer?

Comment: @roman-roman: make no sence, as there is no public view there (https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/summary), what ends in "Public signup for this instance is disabled."

Answer (score 0):

To get the last committed offset of a topic partitions you can use the [`KafkaConsumer.committed(TopicPartition partition)`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#committed-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-) function.

```
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition());
Long committedOffset = consumer.committed(topicPartition).offset();
System.out.println("last committed offset: " + committedOffset);
```

Comment: committed function returns last committed offset by consumer but what actually asked is last committed offset by transactional producer.